# Is it necessary to have mysql column names to begin with letters?

Tags: mysql, syntax, create-table

Consider the following CREATE TABLE query :

```
CRAETE TABLE tablename (100 VARCHAR(10), 200 VARCHAR(10));
```

In this query, `100` and `200` are column names. Is it possible to create tables like this ?

Comment: You can use backticks for this...

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html)

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but you need to wrap those values with backticks.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename 
(
`100` VARCHAR(10), 
`200` VARCHAR(10)
);
```